# Send Openssl Client Hello with extended master secret disabled

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

For testing purpose, I need to simulate a SSL request with EMS - Extended master secret disabled on my Ubuntu machine.

I checked the official openssl page https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation, but could not find any flags/options that I could use in order to compile openssl without the EMS option.

The client always reports EMS as 'Yes', how do I set it to 'No'? Please provide inputs.

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx

openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1-dev  xx XXX xxxx
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: linux-x86_64
compiler: gcc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/compssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1\""  -Wa,--noexecstack
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/compssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific

Server:
sudo openssl s_server -key 384private-key.pem -cert 384server.pem -accept 443 -www -cipher ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL -comp

Client:
sudo openssl s_client -connect 10.92.0.10:443 -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA -comp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
   i:C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

issuer=C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: ECDSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1050 bytes and written 272 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 384 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 56A50DE80262675795C00BFAFE1A63B6487A83FFE0A7D3AD691C2086E63124DC
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: A3D769131534FAFAB0E5DE59FE9B332911F3C1F28D7668C9AF14078E412AEEF0B04DAB969EDCEC1D1CA963AC58097630
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 39 47 ea b2 1a 38 54 09-56 a7 76 d0 21 81 d2 6a   9G...8T.V.v.!..j
    0010 - 6e d9 b2 10 2f 02 ff 6f-d9 0e 23 4b 3a 7e 84 01   n.../..o..#K:~..
    0020 - f8 86 80 fb ef b1 dc bf-f7 ba 62 c7 e8 eb 48 da   ..........b...H.
    0030 - 6e 03 c2 2d 07 51 e9 b3-df 63 a6 27 06 78 e7 79   n..-.Q...c.'.x.y
    0040 - 20 b4 32 a9 6d 8a ab b8-f2 59 c5 f7 76 25 b9 e7    .2.m....Y..v%..
    0050 - 5e 99 66 4f 45 d1 b1 2b-df f4 0b 7e 70 f7 93 b3   ^.fOE..+...~p...
    0060 - 92 98 51 ee ac d4 ce 68-a0 95 fa de c5 e9 f2 d6   ..Q....h........
    0070 - ed 37 93 e3 64 05 91 1a-32 e9 f2 19 d3 43 98 31   .7..d...2....C.1
    0080 - 72 48 89 0c 37 53 67 1b-b6 09 f9 ce 22 20 9f de   rH..7Sg....." ..
    0090 - a2 12 68 db 8c 44 f9 5b-de a2 fd 39 cd fc e2 1f   ..h..D.[...9....
    00a0 - 30 c0 1a 87 42 25 86 e0-c4 44 9b 53 ee a9 f3 90   0...B%...D.S....

    Start Time: 1508783166
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code in OpenSSL there seems to be no way to disable extended master secrets without changing the source code (search for EXTMS). But you could simply use a version of OpenSSL which does not support extended master secrets yet: instead of using bleeding edge 1.1.1dev simply use 1.0.2 (which should be the default OpenSSL on current Ubuntu anyway).

Comment: Ended up using 1.0.2. Thank you.